# Why does the SMFL key press disable not work?

Tags: c++, sfml

I wanted to disable repetitive key presses on holding so I used this command
`window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)`
It does not work

```
#include<iostream>     
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{  
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"shape change color",sf::Style::Close);
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);
int a=0; 
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        
        sf::Event event;

        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
            window.close();
        }
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
a++;
        std::cout << a << std::endl;

window.clear();
window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it "does not seem to work"? What are you doing? What is supposed to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you misunderstand how [`isKeyPressed`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#a80a04b2f53005886957f49eee3531599) works? It only tells if the key is currently pressed or not, it has nothing to do with key repeats. The "repeat" is in your code because of the loop.

Comment: `setKeyRepeatEnabled` affects what gets reported as an event in the event loop (i.e. whether `pollEvent` gets repeated `KeyPressed` events), not whether a key is considered to be down *right now*. (Also, you should only be looking at `event.key.code` if the event *is* a key-related event.)

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to check the following sections in the documentation such as [Events](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-events.php#the-keypressed-and-keyreleased-events) and [Keyboard](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php#a80a04b2f53005886957f49eee3531599)

*If a key is held, multiple `KeyPressed` events will be generated, at the default operating system delay (ie. the same delay that applies when you hold a letter in a text editor). To disable repeated `KeyPressed` events, you can call [`window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false)`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#aef9f2b14c10ecba8a8df95dd51c5bb73). On the flip side, it is obvious that KeyReleased events can never be repeated.*

`sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` is the *real-time* input interface, it has nothing to do with events and it doesn't make sense to mix them.You can try:

```
while(window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
        window.close();
}
```

and

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Please:

- read the documentation and tutorials
- use the [forum](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php#c3) when you have problems